# flask jsonify not showing in html (ajax)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, flask

I have 3 forms on the same html page and one of them is to upload a csv file.  This form correctly uploads (received on server) but the resulting response from the server is not displayed in the html - but instead just in the browser as raw/parsed object: [click for screenshot of browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07XrP.png).

This is the html:

```
    <div class="container">
       <div class="">
     <div class="jumbotron" style="overflow-x:scroll; white-space: nowrap;">
        <form id="upload" name="form_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/uploadcsv">
           <div class="col">
              <input type="file" name="data_file" />
              <button id="btn_upload" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Upload</button>
           </div>
        </form>
```

And this is where it should display:

```
<div class="table table-hover">
   <div id="firsthead">
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript for the form:

```
   <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var upload_data = new FormData($('#upload')[0]);
      $("#button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            data: upload_data,
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/uploadcsv',
            success: function(d){
              $("#firsthead").html(d.head_table);
          }
        });
      });
  });</script>
```

Here is the flask app:

```
@app.route('/uploadcsv', methods=["POST"])
def uploadcsv():
    print('hello uploadcsv')
    print('type (request)', type (request.files['data_file']))
    f = request.files['data_file']
    if not f:
        return "No file"
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    print('df.head(): ', df.head())
    df.to_csv('../data/df.csv')
    head1 = print_head(df)
    print('the head', head1)
    columns = list(df.columns)
    return jsonify(head_table = head1)
```

I can't understand why this is not working - because I have an almost identical situation in the same page, where it does work.  The only difference is that the good form is not uploading a file.

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Try set "**cache, processData, contentType**" to **false**

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // submit event
    $("#upload").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var upload_data = new FormData($('#upload')[0]);
      $.ajax({
        data: upload_data,
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),

        // Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,

        success: function(d) {
          $("#firsthead").html(d.head_table);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: No difference :(       - but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I've copy your code to my project, and found something wrong about $("#button").click() event. If I click it, I will jump to the form url. So I change it to $("#upload").submit(function(e){}) and it works for me. I can get the file data in the server file.

Comment: And very important, you should make sure the Request URL is ok, because I saw you make it as a relative path. I make it as same as you, then the Status Code is 301 which means Moved Permanently and then the url jump to "/uploadcsv/" with "GET" method. I change it to absolute url and the request is ok. So you'd better check again of the form url or just press F12 in chrome to see where does the ajax actually go.

Comment: hmm - I'm not getting the same results as you.  BTW my code is available at https://github.com/howardvickers/no-code-ml/ (app.py, index.html, regressions.py) - Your comments are really appreciated!

Comment: There is a little mistake I just found. You should move your upload_data declaration to the submit closure, otherwise it will be empty. (Happy for your problem sovled)

Comment: Unfortunately moving the upload_data hasn't changed things.  Too bad :(

Comment: I've cloned your repository and configure python development environment. I move `var upload_data = new FormData($('#upload')[0]);` to the button click closure function. It turns out that **upload_data** is ok for request. After I upload a 1.txt and click the button and app.py throw a exception which is **parse error**, then I upload a 1.csv, but app.py give me **No such file or directory**. I create a directory near src dir, and finally the app.py return the json and **df.csv** is written. (global_y,train_model,run_models will make errors so I delete it. You should check your code carefully.)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what is happening is that the default behaviour of the form is not disabled and on submit, it is redirecting to the result

Try to explicitly call the form submit and preventDefault

```
<script>

    $("#upload").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

      $(document).ready(function(){
        var upload_data = new FormData($('#upload')[0]);
          $("#button").click(function(){
              $.ajax({
                data: upload_data,
                type : 'POST',
                url : '/uploadcsv',
                success: function(d){
                  $("#firsthead").html(d.head_table);
              }
            });
          });
      });</script>
```

Comment: This didn't work either - but thank you for the suggestion.